# Python. Динамическая подстановка имени типа класса

Tags: python, django, типы-данных, класс

Необходимо реализовать метод обращения к БД с целью извлечения определённого экземпляра - записи с конкретным номером, например средствами фреймворка Django. Для этой цели сейчас используется функция:

```
def get_instance(pk=None):
    ''' возвращает экземпляр модели из БД по ключю pk'''
    instance = Entry.objects.filter(id=pk) // Entry - тип модели в БД, он же класс объектов
    return instance[0] if instance.exists() else None
```

В приведенной функции используется конкретно заданное имя класса.

Как в этом случае можно обратиться к другой модели в БД, динамически подставив её тип в параметры данного метода? Например, с помощью параметра classType и какой синтаксис будет у classType?

```
 def get_instance(classType, pk=None):
    instance = classType.objects.filter(id=pk) // classType- тип модели в БД, он же класс объектов
    return instance[0] if instance.exists() else None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `first`. Он вернет `None`, если нужных объектов не окажется

```py
def get_instance(classType, pk=None):
    return classType.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
```

А взять класс по имени можно с помощью `getattr`

```py
from myapp import models
class_name = 'MyModel'
model = getattr(models, class_name)
model.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Сработал тривиальный вариант подстановки типа класса:**

```
def get_instance(classType, pk=None):
    return type(classType()).objects.filter(id=pk).first()
```

**Результат выполнения (Python 3.6):**

```
>>> type(Entry)
<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'> // тип, шаблон класса
>>> type(Entry())
<class 'app.models.Entry'> // тип экземпляра класса
>>> get_instance(Entry, 1)
<Entry: id:1 № НЗН-1 от 13.05.2020> // экземпляр из БД
```